# Registering an Azure Functions in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Do I register an Azure Function as a "Web app/API" app in my Azure Active Directory? If so, what would be the "Sign-on URL" for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Function is probably going to kind of like an API.

In case of APIs, the Sign-on URL does not matter.
It will also be used as a reply URL by default, but if there is no user redirections, reply URLs do not matter.

So it can be your Function's URL.